# WinRT - Setting control properties from static event

Tags: user-interface, controls, winrt-xaml, static-methods

I have an WinRT Store App that uses the camera as a barcode reader.  Because some devices have such a bad camera the scan will not work.  I have added a field in my settings flyout (setttings.xaml) to pick a camera or turn it off, save the selection to the ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.  I have to notify the MainPage.xaml of the change and remove the camera image and the border that surrounds it.  I am doing this throught a custom event (which works), but the event handler appears must be static, and static methods do not have access to UI controls.  How can I edit my control's Visibility parameter??

In Settings.xaml.cs:

```
...
MainPage.SettingsChanged(this, null);
...
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
internal static async void SettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (settingsManager.Camera=="Off")
    {
        //these won't compile, it doesn't even see my control in Intelisense
        borderCapture.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        videoCapture.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

If I put somenon-UI related code in the If statement it compiles and runs correctly, so I know my event is wired correctly.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a settings changed event in Settings.Xaml.cs as given below

```
   public static event EventHandler SettingsChanged;
```

Hooke up this event from MainPage.Xaml.cs constructor

```
     public MainPage()
        {
              this.InitializeComponent();
              Settings.SettingsChanged += SettingsFlyout_SettingsChanged;
        }

     void SettingsFlyout_SettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (settingsManager.Camera=="Off")
           {                 
             borderCapture.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            videoCapture.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
           }
        }
```

**Suggestion**

Its better to declare the event in view model and raise the event from code behind whenever needed .

Comment: I also had to change the call on my settings page to fire a local event.  'MainPage.SettingsChanged(this, null);' had to be changed to simply, 'SettingsChanged(this, null);'.   This solution worked like a charm.